# Enum Condition in Linq Query in C#

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, enums

I want to add `Enum` Condition in Linq Query even if Enum datamember is null or empty

I had added `ALL` in model for Filter purpose so that if user select ALL then all data should be displayed

[image: Web Screen]

Data Model :

```
    public partial class AuditTable
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        public int KeyFieldID { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DateTimeStamp { get; set; }
        public EntityType DataModel { get; set; }
        public string ValueBefore { get; set; }
        public string ValueAfter { get; set; }
        public string Changes { get; set; }
        public AuditActionType AuditActionTypeENUM { get; set; }

        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeCode { get; set; }
        public string Remarks { get; set; }
        public string IPAddress { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }
 public enum AuditActionType
    {
        All = 1,
        Create,
        Update,
        Delete
    }

    public enum EntityType
    {
        All = 1,
        BasicDetails,
        EmployeeDetails,
        PersonalDetails                
    }
```

Below code is working fine but had to repeat same query 4 times. I want to combine below query into one

```
if (eType == EntityType.All)
 if (aType == AuditActionType.All)
  AuditTrail = ent.tblAuditTable.Where(s => s.KeyFieldID == ID && s.EmployeeCode.Contains(code) && s.UserName.Contains(username)).OrderByDescending(s => s.DateTimeStamp).ToList(); 
 else
  AuditTrail = ent.tblAuditTable.Where(s => s.KeyFieldID == ID && s.AuditActionTypeENUM == aType && s.EmployeeCode.Contains(code) && s.UserName.Contains(username)).OrderByDescending(s => s.DateTimeStamp).ToList(); 
else
if (aType == AuditActionType.All)
 AuditTrail = ent.tblAuditTable.Where(s => s.KeyFieldID == ID && s.DataModel == eType && s.EmployeeCode.Contains(code) && s.UserName.Contains(username)).OrderByDescending(s => s.DateTimeStamp).ToList();
else
 AuditTrail = ent.tblAuditTable.Where(s => s.KeyFieldID == ID && s.AuditActionTypeENUM == aType && s.DataModel == eType && s.EmployeeCode.Contains(code) && s.UserName.Contains(username)).OrderByDescending(s => s.DateTimeStamp).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can chain `Where()` statements.

```
var baseQuery = ent.tblAuditTable.Where(s => s.KeyFieldID == ID && s.EmployeeCode.Contains(code) && s.UserName.Contains(username));

var realQuery = baseQuery;

if (eType != EntityType.All){
  realQuery = realQuery.Where(s=>s.DataModel == eType);
}

if (aType != EntityType.All){
  realQuery = realQuery.Where(x=>s.AuditActionTypeENUM == aType);
}

var result = realQuery.OrderByDescending(s => s.DateTimeStamp).ToList()

AuditTrail = result;
```

Answer (score 1):

All together in one query?

Like this:

```
bool eTypeIsAll = eType == EntityType.All;
bool aTypeIsAll = aType == AuditActionType.All;
AuditTrail =
    ent.tblAuditTable
       .Where(s => s.KeyFieldID == ID
                   && (
                       eTypeIsAll ? (
                            (
                                !aTypeIsAll ?
                                    s.AuditActionTypeENUM == aType
                                    : true
                            )

                       )
                       : (
                            (
                                !aTypeIsAll ?
                                    s.AuditActionTypeENUM == aType
                                    : true
                            )
                            && s.DataModel == eType

                       )

                   )
                   && s.EmployeeCode.Contains(code)
                   && s.UserName.Contains(username))
        .OrderByDescending(s => s.DateTimeStamp)
        .ToList();
```

Personally, i prefer this way. But many people say that @Jehof method is more readable.

Comment: Not only the other way is more readable, but also generates better SQL queries (with the current query providers).

Comment: I tought the same, but I've testes several different approachs in my playground and didn't find a big difference, just 5-10ms from query to query... And since you will not read the SQL query by yourself it doesn't really matter.

Comment: I think it's more about personal preference

Answer (score 0):

You should work with IQueryables. 
There is no need to write your query in one single line. You can Spread it in multiple sub queries.

```
var queryAble= ent.tblAuditTbale.where(s=>s.KeyFieldId ==Id);

if(eType !=EntityType.All)  
 queryAble = queryAble.where(s=> s.DataModel==eTYpe);

If(aType!= AuditActionType.All)    
 queryAble = queryAble.where(s=> s.AuditActionTypeENUM == aType);
```

Finnally (Query will execute now)

```
AuditTrail = queryAble.ToList();
```